# Using R to stack non-numerical dataset

Tags: r, stack

I have a data.frame of GO terms that I need to stack. 
df looks like:

```
> head(GO_info)
      V2 
Gene1 GO:0003674,GO:0005215,GO:0005216,GO:0005575
Gene2 GO:0000462,GO:0002181,GO:0003674,GO:0003735
```

But I want this dataframe stacked, including the headers "ind" and "values" like:

```
ind values
Gene1 GO:0003674
Gene1 GO:0005215
etc
```

I tried to use:

```
GO_info2 <- stack(GO_info)
```

But this is not working, the R helpfunction did not help me much. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I saw that in my >head(GO_info) is a minor mistake. Column 1 has a header called V1, so it looks like:
V1        V2
Gene1 GO:0003674,GO:0005215,GO:0005216,GO:0005575
Gene2 GO:0000462,GO:0002181,GO:0003674,GO:0003735

Because the code of A. Suliman is not working I tried it now as follows:

`GOterm <- data.frame(V2=unlist(strsplit(as.character(GOterm1$V2),",")))`

But than V1 is completely removed while this is important as identifier. Any help?

Comment: If you have two columns V1 and V2 then you can do `df %>% separate_rows(V2,sep = ',')`. Then change columns names using `colnames(df) <- c('ind','values')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 library(tidyr)
 df %>% separate(V2,into = c('ind','values'),sep = '\\s') %>%  #separate V2 to inds and values at space \\s
        separate_rows(values,sep = ',')                        #separate values to multiple rows at ','

      ind     values
  1 Gene1 GO:0003674
  2 Gene1 GO:0005215
  3 Gene1 GO:0005216
  4 Gene1 GO:0005575
  5 Gene2 GO:0000462
  6 Gene2 GO:0002181
  7 Gene2 GO:0003674
  8 Gene2 GO:0003735
```

## data

```
 df<-read.table(text="
           V2 
           'Gene1 GO:0003674,GO:0005215,GO:0005216,GO:0005575'
           'Gene2 GO:0000462,GO:0002181,GO:0003674,GO:0003735'
           ",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment but it seems not to work yet. I tried implementing it:
    `GOterm <- GO_info %>% separate(V2,into = c('ind','values'),sep = '\\s') %>%

GOterm=new stacked datafile and GO_info my old df with 1000s of gene ID's. I get the following warning:
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 24140 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...]. 

It just replaces my gene name (like "TRINITY_DN100009_c0_g1") into values 1,2,3,4.